# How to suppress warnings in vim-latex?

Tags: vim, latex

I want to hide a couple of problematic warnings in vim-latex, but I can't seem to work out the syntax.

I currently have:

```
let g:tex_IgnoredWarnings = 
    \'Underfull'."\n".
    \'Overfull'."\n".
    \'specifier changed to'."\n".
    \'You have requested'."\n".
    \'Missing number, treated as zero.'."\n".
    \'There were undefined references'."\n".
    \'Citation %.%# undefined'."\n".
    \'Double space found.'."\n"
let g:Tex_IgnoreLevel = 8
```

To me, that looks correct per [the documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-compiling.html#Tex_IgnoredWarnings), but the "Double Space Found" warning still appears (to clarify, by 'still appears' I mean that it's highlighted on the left of the screen with `S>`).

Any ideas?

Comment: I notice most of those warnings don't end will periods. Does it work if you change `\'Double space found.'."\n"` to `\'Double space found'."\n"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property you're setting should start with an uppercase letter (`g:Tex_IgnoredWarnings` as opposed to `g:tex_IgnoredWarnings`. The way you have it now, vim-latex is using the default value for `g:Tex_IgnoredWarnings` and not your desired overrides.